# python: can't open an existing file even if the path has already been clearly added

Tags: python

I am using python 2.7.11 and I have downloaded setuptools-2.2 for its included `setup.py` file. Then I did a `python setup.py install` (This command is successful), and I added the path for this `setup.py` file to `~/.bash_profile`.

```
export PATH=/opt/python2711/lib/python2.7/site-packages/:$PATH
export PATH=/path-to-setuptools/setuptools-2.2/:$PATH
```

However, when I tried to install another software (./pybombs install uhd), my computer kept complaining:

> Build failed. Re-trying with reduced makewidth and higher verbosity.
>   python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I actually tried to add the path of that egg file as well, but it couldn't help either. I don't know much about this `setup.py` file. Could somebody point out how to fix this compiling error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It will be helpful for others if you add information about how you are doing in the system with means how you are calling with extension or with out like so some one get you the right answer my guess is please check weather it is in the correct mode or not

Comment: `python /path/to/setup.py install`

Comment: alternatively you can use **sys.path.append("/path/to_Setups_Directory")** and then **import setup.py**.

Answer (score 1):

**add your path in `~/.profile`**
`export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/dir` 
`~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.`

### how ever the path variable is in

**`/etc/environment`** : file open and add the path here you should log in as root

Comment: NO you will have `~/.profile` file in default it is executed once shell login remove your `~/.bash_profile` before removing please keep bakc up

Comment: I don't have such a file in CentOS

Comment: @Cindy ok fine add it in your `~/.bash_profile` if it works leave it or else go to `/etc/environment` you can see the PATH variable add your path it works